# How do I bind the ListBox of a ComboBox in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am looking to make a bind that allows me to place a certain value depending on the key pressed by the user.
Here is an example code in which I do it:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

v=Tk()

combo = ttk.Combobox(values=['item1','item2','item3','item4'], state='readonly')
combo.current(0)
combo.pack()

def function(Event):
    if(Event.char in '1234'):
        combo.set(f'item{Event.char}')

combo.bind('<Key>', function)
v.mainloop()
```

They will tell me "If that works, what are you doing asking this?"
Well it turns out that if the Combobox is deployed, the bind stops working.
How could the problem be solved?

---

I know that this part of the question should not be asked, since it has nothing to do with the problem in question. But I would like to ask that if something is wrong in this question, or misspelled, or whatever, be informed. The page of "how to ask a good question" does not serve me, since from my point of view, I do everything as they say there.
I did my best to make what is written here as detailed and understandable as possible.
Hope your understanding, thank you.

Comment: What is "deployed"?

Comment: I mean when the button to the right of the ComboBox is clicked and a ListBox appears below.
Is there a more appropriate word? "displayed" works?
Thanks for your question!

Comment: You are binding to the `Combobox` only. When the ListBox is displayed, the focus is no longer on your `Combobox` so the keys won't work. You can however do `v.bind_all('<Key>', function)` on the whole application.

Comment: But what if you had more than one Combobox?
How could I determine which of the two calls the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what Henry Yik proposed and studying what was returned by Event.widget, I found the solution to the problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

v=Tk()

# I create two test combobox
for _ in range(2):
    combo = ttk.Combobox(values=['item1','item2','item3','item4'], state='readonly')
    combo.current(0)
    combo.pack()

# I create a test entry to test if the function correctly recognizes when it should be executed
entrada = Entry()
entrada.pack()

def function(Event):
    """
    If Event.widget is a str and ends with ".popdown.f.l" I consider it to be the Listbox,
    I get the path of the Combobox it belongs to and convert it to a widget.
    Afterwards, I set the value of Event.widget to that of the supposed combobox.
    """
    if(isinstance(Event.widget, str) and Event.widget.endswith(".popdown.f.l")):
        Event.widget = v._nametowidget(Event.widget[:-len(".popdown.f.l")])

        
    # If Event.widget is not a Combobox, it stops the execution of the function.
    if(not isinstance(Event.widget, ttk.Combobox)):
        return

    if(Event.char in '1234'):
        Event.widget.set(f'item{Event.char}')

v.bind_all('<Key>', function)
v.mainloop()
```